# mp3 no suena con API de Android mayor o igual a 26

Tags: android-studio, android-notifications

Con Android Studio y Kotlin, he diseñado una alarma común que suena a la hora que deseo.
Para las API < 26, suena el contenido del archivo alarm.mp3 al cual apunta, pero para las API >= 26 emite un sonido por defecto del sistema en vez del mp3. Entiendo que la diferencia entre ambas APIs es que las mayores o iguales a 26 utilizan lo que se llama un canal de notificación. No estoy seguro si eso genera la diferencia en el resultado. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?. Muchas gracias. Publico el código del NotificationService.kt utilizado.
He aquí mi código:

```
    package com.example.alarma
    
    import android.annotation.TargetApi
    import android.app.*
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
    import android.media.RingtoneManager
    import android.net.Uri
    import android.os.Build
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
    import java.time.Year
    import java.util.*
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
    import kotlin.collections.ArrayList
    
    
    class NotificationService : IntentService {
        private var notificationManager: NotificationManager? = null
        private var pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null
        var notification: Notification? = null
        lateinit var alarmDao: AlarmDao
        constructor(name: String?) : super(name) {}
        constructor() : super("SERVICE") {}
    
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
            val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name)
            val context = this.applicationContext
            notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val mIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            val res = this.resources
            var message = ""
            var date = ""
            var time = ""
            //Se determina a qué hora corresponde la alarma a leer:
            val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
            // Se lee, procesa y elimnina cada alarma leida:
            alarmDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(this).alarmDao()
            val alarms = ArrayList<Alarm>(alarmDao.getAlarms())
            val alarm = alarms[0]
            message = alarm.alarmText
            alarmDao.deleteAlarm(alarm)
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                message = message + "ando por API >= 26"
                val NOTIFY_ID = 0 // ID of notification
                val title = NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID // Default Channel
                val pendingIntent: PendingIntent
                val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder
                var notifManager =
                    context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                if (notifManager == null) {
                    notifManager =
                        context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                }
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                var mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID // default_channel_id
                )
                if (mChannel == null) {
                    mChannel = NotificationChannel(
                        NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                        "Titulo:",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT // default_channel_id, title, importance
                    )
                    mChannel.enableVibration(true)
                    mChannel.vibrationPattern =
                        longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
                    notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
                }
                builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID // default_channel_id
                )
                mIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    mIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
                builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification) // required
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_notification))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setVibrate(longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400))
                val notification = builder.build()
                var notif:Int=alarm.id
                notificationManager!!.notify(notif, notification)
                startForeground(1, notification)
            } else {
                message = message + "ando por API < 26"
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    1,
                    mIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
                notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_notification))
                    .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .setContentText(message).build()
                var notif:Int=alarm.id
                notificationManager!!.notify(notif, notification)
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: hola amigo, no sabemos que estas haciendo mal por que no has dicho cual es el problema exactamente ... cual es el resultado, no suena, alguna error en particular en el código o compilando??? intentaste hacer el debug con los breackpoint para ver por donde entra tu código al validar las versiones, realmente debes aclarar tu publicación y te recomiendo que la incluyas en tu POST editándolo,

Comment: Para las API < 26, suena el contenido del archivo alarm.mp3 al cual apunta, pero para las API >= 26 emite un sonido por defecto del sistema en vez del mp3.

Comment: y eso es un problema ??? que es lo que esperas que haga entonces??? no es eso??? pensaba que esa condición la habías creado a propósito ...

Comment: Sigo aclarando. Lo que me sucede es que para API < 26, suena el contenido del archivo alarm.mp3 al cual apunta, o sea que HACE LO QUE DEBE. Pero para las API >= 26 emite un sonido por defecto del sistema en vez de sonar el mp3. En el còdigo expuesto está el IF que pregunta por la versión de API y ejecuta la línea .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm)) en ambos casos. En un caso anda (cuando codigo sale por el ELSE) y en el otro no (cuando el código sale por el IF).

Comment: no será que esas versiones tienen sonidos distinto ???

Comment: estas esperando que sea el mismo sonido; puedes validar que en la sección donde no escuchas el mp3 exista el recurso???

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente como comentas ahora se usa un Notification Chanel y este canal ahora ya no puede ser modificado, por lo tanto sus propiedades como el sonido tampoco una vez declarado a menos que lo elimines y lo vuelvas a crear.

Con respeto a el problema debes asegurar que el archivo `alarm.mp3` que se encuentra dentro del directorio `/raw` definido como sonido para el Canal:

```
.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm))
```

en verdad se pueda reproducir, trata de abrirlo para que lo compruebes.

Posteriormente revisa en la configuraciòn si tienes permitido para tu aplicaciòn la reproducciòn de sonido, ya que esto puede estar desactivado y esta configuraciòn la realiza el usuario ("Allow playing sound"):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El archivo `alarm.mp3` suena tanto en APIs < 26 como en las >= 26 (Android Oreo). Efectivamente el problema era que para las versiones >= 26, debe setearse a nivel de canal. En concreto antes de las sentencias:

```
                ...
                mChannel.enableVibration(true)
                mChannel.vibrationPattern =
                    longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
                notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
```

debe agregarse la sentencia que setea el canal, quedando por lo tanto de la siguiente manera:

```
              ...
              mChannel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ 
                        getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm),null)
              mChannel.enableVibration(true)
              mChannel.vibrationPattern =
              longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
              notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
```

Una vez creado el canal (en los dispositivos se conoce como CATEGORÍA), queda para las próximas ejecuciones de la apk. Esto también significa que no siempre marcha bien para la primera ejecución, dado que el canal se crea en esta primera ejecución de la apk en el dispositivo que sea.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar tu respuesta](/help/accepted-answer) una vez que transcurra el tiempo mínimo.